# Does distance increase equally in equal time intervals under the influence of gravity?

Tags: calculus, physics

Quick question.

If an object falls under the influence of gravity near the Earths surface, is the distance traveled increased by equal amounts in equal time intervals?

I thought that this would be true. Wouldn't gravity be the only thing moving the object? So it'd be constant right?

Thanks

Comment: $$S=ut+\frac12gt^2$$

Comment: Ok then it would be true right?

Comment: If you mean whether the distance traveled from time 0 to 1 is the same from time 1 to 2, then it is false (because the object is accelerating) edit: sorry, should be displacement, not a scientist haha

Comment: http://www.school-for-champions.com/science/gravity_equations_falling_displacement.htm#.Uw4X2Mu6at8

Answer (score 1):

No, clearly not. As an object falls, it "accelerates downward", meaning the velocity of the object as it travels downward *increases*, reaching it's maximum velocity *just before* hitting the ground. So if it takes the object, say, 15 seconds to hit the ground after being dropped, then it will travel the least distance in the first second, and the most distance between $14$ and $15$ seconds.